# Block div causing parent float to expand to 100%

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a right-floated, fluid-width div that sits nicely next to a another fluid-width, NON-floated column.

Everything works fine until I put another fluid-width div into that right-floated column, at which point it expands to 100% and drops the non-floated column below it. The only thing I can do to fix this is give the div causing the issue a fixed pixel width, but I don't want to do this as it needs to expand to its parent float but not beyond that. Here's an example of the problem:

```
    <div style="overflow:hidden;width:800px;">
    <div style="min-width:600px;min-height:200px;float:right;background:#FAA;">
    <div id="floatContent" style="max-width:88%;">Here's some long string of text that makes the width of the parent float expand out to 100% of *its* parent, rather than shrinking the content to its original width (100% minus the width of the non-floated element</div>
  </div>
    <div style="min-width:200px;min-height:200px;background:#CCC;">Some non-floated content</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas? Thanks very much.

[**JSFiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/rv7PM/1/)

Comment: Is it necessary that the `max-width: 88%;` in the div containing the long text is in percentages? Because the problem is solved when you put there `max-width: 600px;` right?

Comment: I think it is possible what you want, maybe you can edit your question and explain what you really want, and which pixel-values you want to specify exactly and which you want to leave in percentages. Then the answer to this question will be relatively easy I believe.

Comment: Thanks Yeti - the problem is that I need the outer floated div to have a fluid width along with its contents. Both of those can be within a fixed width div, though.